# Is there a way I can flatten a complex datatypes array of array of struct without using explode function?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I am trying to flatten out a complex schema in PySpark. The data is too huge to go for an explode function (I read that the explode function is a very expensive function). Here is how my schema looks like -

```
 |-- A: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- B: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- C: string (nullable = true)
```

I would like to flatten it out to

```
|-- A: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- B: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- C: string (nullable = true)
```

I tried `df.select("A.*")` but I get an exception

```
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Can only star expand struct data types. Attribute: `ArrayBuffer(A)`;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please post sampel data and expected  output please

Comment: Sorry about that, I will edit the post and post it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check below code.

```
scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- A: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- A: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- B: string (nullable = true)
```

```
scala> df.withColumn("A",expr("flatten(transform(A,x -> array(x.A,x.b)))")).printSchema
root
 |-- A: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

```
scala> df.withColumn("A",flatten($"A")).printSchema
root
 |-- A: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- A: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- B: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Thank you @Srinivas, it is exactly the breakthrough I needed. Small issue if anyone is following this solution, I am using PySpark and after the third transformation, this is how the schema is after it:

`|-- A: array (nullable = true)`
`|    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)`
The columns in struct (A and B) are getting merged into one column if A and B aren't the only rows in the initial struct.

Comment: I'm confused with this The code sample above is done in Pyspark environment where they predominantly run in Python. But  the solution provided is in Scala? How does this all makes any sense?  If I tried using '$' as a predicate for expression evaluation, it will give me syntax errors.

Comment: @awongCM, I have given solution in language which i am aware of it..whoever asked this he got my point.. (know both.. thanks to author). if you want to this solution to work in python ..move everything to inside expr function and remove $ symbol

Comment: If it still not help please raise new question and share with me .. will help you

Comment: @Srinivas.  Don;t worry about it. I understand the point of your solution now.  Thanks very much for sharing this. All good.